# Why is getProperty returning null via PHP ReflectionClass

Tags: php

I am making a new `ReflectionClass`, then setting the protected property `_products` to accessible. It is always returning `null` Am I doing something wrong here? I am on 5.4.11

```
$project  = new ReflectionClass( $instance_of_object );
$property = $project->getProperty( '_products' );
$property->setAccessible( true );
$products = $property->getValue( $project );
```

I am trying to make sure a property is set correctly in my unit tests...

Comment: Edited to have answer above :) 5.4.11

Comment: Are you **sure** that the property is not `null`?

Comment: Do you have any namespaces involved?

Comment: Shouldn't your unit tests be testing the methods, not private properties?  It seems to me that return values of your methods should indicate if there is a problem with the property.

Comment: @hek2mgl The class defaults it to `false`. @Tim The property is set in one function and used in another. It is never returned anywhere so there is no getter. I'd rather get the property rather than adding a method for testing, if I could avoid it.

Comment: Does my example work for you? it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a working simple example. If you can execute it, there must be an error on other place in your code:

```
class The_Class {

    private $_products;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_products = 'foo';
    }
}

$instance_of_class = new The_Class();
$reflClass = new ReflectionClass($instance_of_class);
$member = $reflClass->getProperty('_products');
$member->setAccessible(true);
// Here is an error in your code:
// Note that I'm using $instance_of_class, rather then
// $reflClass as argument to getValue()
var_dump($member->getValue($instance_of_class)); // string(3) "foo"
```

Comment: Interesting... what version are you on? Same as me? Also we default `_products` to `false` ( which I should probably change ) but it was also still saying `null` for me after setting it in the class. I suppose I'll triple check. Does that work for you if you don't set in constructor and default it to 3 in declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but [this on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UbGZWmuy) works for me. I'm using PHP5.3.10

Comment: If you delete the constructor does it still work? Silly I said set it to "3" I meant to say "foo" to see if it will work if it's "foo" from the start

Comment: yep! got `int(3)` when removing the constructor. Again, can you execute my simple example? Just this, nothing more?

Comment: I got out of office but I am gonna try this first thing in the morning. Thanks for the speedy help

Comment: Ok, drop a comment when you've tested it. have a nice evening

Comment: This is working in a test script but not in my unit test. I did `var_dump` on my instance passed into `ReflectionClass` and it is indeed an instance with `_products` equal to `false`. Doing a `var_dump` of the reflection gives nothing useful, but it doesn't in the working example either - just the name of the class it's reflecting

Comment: I just noticed how you use `$instance_of_class` in the `getValue` rather than the `$reflClass` which is what my example is doing. It's funny you said I must have an error in my code, fixed it in your example, and didn't notice that specific thing either ;)

Comment: `I just noticed how you use $instance_of_class in the getValue rather than the $reflClass which is what my example is doing.` Yeah! thats it!! I have overseen it in your example! :)